# How read Group By of core data - swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I have bellow `query`:

```
 let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Cohorts")
 fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["ctype", "is_selected"]
 fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["ctype", "is_selected"]
 fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
 let results = try self.privateManagedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as Array
```

And bellow is my result value from above `query`:

```
(
        {
        ctype = offline;
        "is_selected" = 0;
    },
        {
        ctype = online;
        "is_selected" = 0;
    }
)
```

How can I read `results` or how can I insert above result to custom model like bellow?

```
struct TEST
{
    var ctype : String
    var is_selected : Int
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one line

```
let testArray = results.map{TEST(ctype: $0["ctype"] as! String, is_selected: $0["is_selected"] as! Int)}
```

Comment: @ vadian. It say Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts, here -> $0...

Comment: Cast `results` to something reasonable `let results = try self.privateManagedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [[String:Any]]`. Just `Array` is pointless.

Comment: @ vadian. Thank's a lot.